# Javascript || not working

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I'm Working on a banking application in which i have one **drop-down** box to select **Mode of Payment** and i have two text fields for **Acc No** and **Bank Name**.

I have three inputs for **Mode of payment**: 1.Bank Transfer,2.Cash and 3.DD/Cheque.Now I would like to display a pop up message If the user selects the Mode of payment as Bank Transfer or DD/Cheque and leaving the two text fields i.e.,Acc No and Bank Name as blank.

**MY JavaScript**:

```
if ($F('personnel_bank_detail_mode_of_payment') == 'Bank Transfer' || 'DD/Cheque') 
{
    if ($F('personnel_bank_detail_account_number') == '')
    {
        "* Please Enter Bank Account Number\n";
    }
    if ($F('personnel_bank_detail_bank_id') == '') 
    {
        "* Select Bank Name\n";
    }
}
```

The above code is working if the user selects **Bank Transfer** but it is not working for **DD/Cheque**. How Could i make my code to work for both.Any useful suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: If you do `if(a == b || c)`, JS will think it is `if( (a==b) || c )`, which will be always `true` because `c` (`'DD/Cheque'`) is not empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to repeat what you're comparing.

```
if ($F('personnel_bank_detail_mode_of_payment') == 'Bank Transfer' || $F('personnel_bank_detail_mode_of_payment') == 'DD/Cheque')
```

If you're having some trouble with this, you can make this more obvious to yourself in the future by using parentheses around every statement.

```
if ((something == otherthing) || (something == someotherthing))
```

For the behaviour you're expecting, both sides of the `||` need to be something that evaluate to a boolean, which the `==` operator returns.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.It is weird i missed that.

Answer (score 1):

The `if` condition should rather be :

```
if ($F('personnel_bank_detail_mode_of_payment') == 'Bank Transfer' || $F('personnel_bank_detail_mode_of_payment') == 'DD/Cheque') {
// do your stuff
}
```

There is definitely something more you need to know about `Logical Operators` in JavaScript [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators).